# Jtoolbar isn't displaying

Tags: java, swing

I am new to stackoverflow and to learning Java. I am creating an application for one of my courses in college and we have to create  a text editor with a menu bar and a toolbar. I have been able to get the menubar to work, but the toolbar isn't displaying even though it isn't breaking in code. Would anyone know what this is happening?

```
import com.sun.deploy.ui.AboutDialog;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.RETURN;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.UndoableEditEvent;
import javax.swing.event.UndoableEditListener;
import javax.swing.undo.CannotUndoException;
import javax.swing.undo.UndoManager;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DoesThisWork extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DoesThisWork();
    }

    //============================================
    // FIELDS
    //============================================

    // Menus
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenu editMenu;
    private JMenu formatMenu;
    private JMenu helpMenu;
    private JMenuItem newFile, openFile, saveFile, saveAsFile, pageSetup, printFile, exit;
    private JMenuItem undoEdit, redoEdit, selectAll, copy, paste, cut;
    private JMenu fontColor, fontSize;
    private JMenuItem about;
    private JMenuItem subColorRed, subColorBlue, subColorGreen, subColorBlack;
    private JMenuItem subTimes, subArial, subCourier, subVerdana;

    //Toolbar Buttons
    private JButton red;
    private JButton blue;
    private JButton green;
    private JButton black;
//    private JButton newFile, openFile, saveFile, saveAsFile, pageSetup, printFile, exit;
//    private JMenuItem undoEdit, redoEdit, selectAll, copy, paste, cut;
//    private JMenu fontColor, fontSize;
//    private JMenuItem about;
//    private JMenuItem subColorRed, subColorBlue, subColorGreen, subColorBlack;
//    private JMenuItem sub8, sub10, sub12, sub50;


    // Window
    private JFrame editorWindow;

    // Text Area
    private Border textBorder;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Font textFont;

    // Window
    private JFrame window;

    // Printing
    private PrinterJob job;
    public PageFormat format;

    // Is File Saved/Opened
    private boolean opened = false;
    private boolean saved = false;

    // Record Open File for quick saving
    private File openedFile;

    // Undo manager for managing the storage of the undos
    // so that the can be redone if requested
    private UndoManager undo;

    //Toolbar
    private JToolBar toolBar;


    //============================================
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    //============================================

    public DoesThisWork() {
        super("Text Editor");

        // Create Menus
        fileMenu();
        editMenu();
        formatMenu();
        helpMenu();

        // Create Text Area
        createTextArea();

        // Create Undo Manager for managing undo/redo commands
        undoMan();

        // Create Window
        createEditorWindow();

        // Create Toolbar
        createToolBar();


    }

    private JFrame createEditorWindow() {
        editorWindow = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        editorWindow.setVisible(true);
        editorWindow.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        editorWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Create Menu Bar
        editorWindow.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        editorWindow.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        editorWindow.pack();
        // Centers application on screen
        editorWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // Create ToolBar
        //editorWindow.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        return editorWindow;
    }

    private JTextArea createTextArea() {
        //textBorder = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
        textArea = new JTextArea(30, 50);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(textBorder, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 0, 0)));

        textFont = new Font("Verdana", 0, 14);
        textArea.setFont(textFont);

        scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        return textArea;
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(formatMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        return menuBar;
    }

    private JToolBar createToolBar(){

        toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setFloatable(true);
        red = new JButton("Red");
        red.setToolTipText("Click here to change font color to Red");
        blue = new JButton("Blue");
        blue.setToolTipText("Click here to change font color to Blue");
        green = new JButton("Green");
        green.setToolTipText("Click here to change font color to Green");
        black = new JButton("Black");
        black.setToolTipText("Click here to change font color to Black");
        //add(toolBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Toolbar Color Buttons
        toolBar.add(red);
        toolBar.add(blue);
        toolBar.add(green);
        toolBar.add(black);
        add(toolBar, BorderLayout.WEST);

        //ToolBar tb = new ToolBar();
        toolBar.setVisible(true);


        return toolBar;
    }

    private UndoManager undoMan() {
        // Listener for undo and redo functions to document
        undo = new UndoManager();
        textArea.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {

            @Override
            public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
                undo.addEdit(e.getEdit());
            }
        });

        return undo;
    }

    private void fileMenu() {
        // Create File Menu
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        fileMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));

        // Add file menu items
        newFile = new JMenuItem("New");
        newFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        newFile.addActionListener(this);
        newFile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        newFile.setEnabled(true);

        openFile = new JMenuItem("Open...");
        openFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        openFile.addActionListener(this);
        openFile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        openFile.setEnabled(true);

        saveFile = new JMenuItem("Save");
        saveFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        saveFile.addActionListener(this);
        saveFile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        saveFile.setEnabled(true);

        saveAsFile = new JMenuItem("Save As...");
        saveAsFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        saveAsFile.addActionListener(this);
        saveAsFile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        saveAsFile.setEnabled(true);

        pageSetup = new JMenuItem("Page Setup...");
        pageSetup.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_U);
        pageSetup.addActionListener(this);
        pageSetup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        pageSetup.setEnabled(true);

        printFile = new JMenuItem("Print...");
        printFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        printFile.addActionListener(this);
        printFile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        printFile.setEnabled(true);

        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        exit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        exit.setEnabled(true);

        // Add items to menu
        fileMenu.add(newFile);
        fileMenu.add(openFile);
        fileMenu.add(saveFile);
        fileMenu.add(saveAsFile);
        fileMenu.add(pageSetup);
        fileMenu.add(printFile);
        fileMenu.add(exit);
    }

    private void editMenu() {
        editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        editMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        editMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));

        // Add file menu items
        undoEdit = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        undoEdit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_U);
        undoEdit.addActionListener(this);
        undoEdit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        undoEdit.setEnabled(true);

        redoEdit = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        redoEdit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        redoEdit.addActionListener(this);
        redoEdit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        redoEdit.setEnabled(true);

        selectAll = new JMenuItem("Select All");
        selectAll.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        selectAll.addActionListener(this);
        selectAll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        selectAll.setEnabled(true);

        copy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        copy.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        copy.addActionListener(this);
        copy.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        copy.setEnabled(true);

        paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        paste.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        paste.addActionListener(this);
        paste.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        paste.setEnabled(true);

        cut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        cut.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        cut.addActionListener(this);
        cut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        cut.setEnabled(true);

        // Add items to menu
        editMenu.add(undoEdit);
        editMenu.add(redoEdit);
        editMenu.add(selectAll);
        editMenu.add(copy);
        editMenu.add(paste);
        editMenu.add(cut);
    }
    private void formatMenu() {
        formatMenu = new JMenu("Format");
        formatMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        formatMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 20));

        // Add file menu items
        fontColor= new JMenu("Font Color");
        fontColor.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        fontColor.addActionListener(this);
        fontColor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        fontColor.setEnabled(true);

        fontSize= new JMenu("Font Style");
        fontSize.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        fontSize.addActionListener(this);
        fontSize.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        fontSize.setEnabled(true);

        // Add submenu items
        subColorRed= new JMenuItem("Red");
        subColorRed.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        subColorRed.addActionListener(this);
        subColorRed.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        subColorRed.setEnabled(true);

        subColorBlue= new JMenuItem("Blue");
        subColorBlue.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        subColorBlue.addActionListener(this);
        subColorBlue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        subColorBlue.setEnabled(true);

        subColorGreen= new JMenuItem("Green");
        subColorGreen.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        subColorGreen.addActionListener(this);
        subColorGreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        subColorGreen.setEnabled(true);

        subColorBlack= new JMenuItem("Black");
        subColorBlack.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        subColorBlack.addActionListener(this);
        subColorBlack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        subColorBlack.setEnabled(true);

        subTimes= new JMenuItem("Times New Roman");
        subTimes.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        subTimes.addActionListener(this);
        subTimes.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
        subTimes.setEnabled(true);

        subArial= new JMenuItem("Arial");
        subArial.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        subArial.addActionListener(this);
        subArial.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        subArial.setEnabled(true);

        subCourier= new JMenuItem("Courier");
        subCourier.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        subCourier.addActionListener(this);
        subCourier.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        subCourier.setEnabled(true);

        subVerdana= new JMenuItem("Verdana");
        subVerdana.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        subVerdana.addActionListener(this);
        subVerdana.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        subVerdana.setEnabled(true);

        // Add items to menu
        formatMenu.add(fontColor);
        fontColor.add(subColorRed);
        fontColor.add(subColorBlue);
        fontColor.add(subColorGreen);
        fontColor.add(subColorBlack);
        formatMenu.add(fontSize);
        fontSize.add(subTimes);
        fontSize.add(subArial);
        fontSize.add(subCourier);
        fontSize.add(subVerdana);

    }
    private void helpMenu() {
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        helpMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        helpMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));

        // Add file menu items
        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        about.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        about.addActionListener(this);
        about.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        about.setEnabled(true);

        // Add items to menu
        helpMenu.add(about);
    }
    // Method for saving files - Removes duplication of code
    private void saveFile(File filename) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
            writer.write(textArea.getText());
            writer.close();
            saved = true;
            window.setTitle("Text Editor - " + filename.getName());
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Method for quick saving files
    private void quickSave(File filename) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
            writer.write(textArea.getText());
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Method for opening files
    private void openingFiles(File filename) {
        try {
            openedFile = filename;
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
            textArea.read(reader, null);
            opened = true;
            window.setTitle("Text Editor - " + filename.getName());
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == newFile) {
            new DoesThisWork();
        } else if(event.getSource() == openFile) {
            JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
            open.showOpenDialog(null);
            File file = open.getSelectedFile();
            openingFiles(file);
        } else if(event.getSource() == saveFile) {
            JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();
            File filename = save.getSelectedFile();
            if(opened == false && saved == false) {
                save.showSaveDialog(null);
                int confirmationResult;
                if(filename.exists()) {
                    confirmationResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(saveFile, "Replace existing file?");
                    if(confirmationResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        saveFile(filename);
                    }
                } else {
                    saveFile(filename);
                }
            } else {
                quickSave(openedFile);
            }
        } else if(event.getSource() == saveAsFile) {
            JFileChooser saveAs = new JFileChooser();
            saveAs.showSaveDialog(null);
            File filename = saveAs.getSelectedFile();
            int confirmationResult;
            if(filename.exists()) {
                confirmationResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(saveAsFile, "Replace existing file?");
                if(confirmationResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    saveFile(filename);
                }
            } else {
                saveFile(filename);
            }
        } else if(event.getSource() == pageSetup) {
            job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            format = job.pageDialog(job.defaultPage());
        } else if(event.getSource() == printFile) {
            job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            if(job.printDialog()) {
                try {
                    job.print();
                } catch (PrinterException err) {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if(event.getSource() == exit) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if(event.getSource() == undoEdit) {
            try {
                undo.undo();
            } catch(CannotUndoException cu) {
                cu.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(event.getSource() == redoEdit) {
            try {
                undo.redo();
            } catch(CannotUndoException cur) {
                cur.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(event.getSource() == selectAll) {
            textArea.selectAll();
        }  else if(event.getSource() == copy) {
            textArea.copy();
        } else if(event.getSource() == paste) {
            textArea.paste();
        } else if(event.getSource() == cut) {
            textArea.cut();
        } else if(event.getSource() == about){
            //createAboutFrame();
            JLabel About = new JLabel();
            About.setText("<html>"
                    + "<p>This is a custom Text Editor</p>"
                    + "<p>Built By Todd Eaton, October 2015</p>"
                    + "<p>Brandeis University</p>"
                    + "<p>Master of Software Engineering Candidate</p>");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, About, "About Text Editor", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subColorRed){
            textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subColorBlue) {
            textArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subColorGreen) {
            textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subColorBlack) {
            textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subTimes){
            textFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14);
            textArea.setFont(textFont);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subArial){
            textFont = new Font("Arial", 0, 14);
            textArea.setFont(textFont);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subCourier){
            textFont = new Font("Courier", 0, 14);
            textArea.setFont(textFont);
        } else if(event.getSource() == subVerdana){
            textFont = new Font("Verdana", 0, 14);
            textArea.setFont(textFont);
        }


    }

    //============================================
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    //============================================

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

    public void setTextArea(JTextArea text) {
        textArea = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below comment

```
//editorWindow.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Should be replaced with

```
editorWindow.add(createToolBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

To actually create a toolbar and add it to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your `JToolBar` to the instance of `JFrame` created  by `DoesThisWork`, but this is never actually shown on the screen.

Start by getting rid of `extends JFrame` and rely on the instance of `JFrame` assigned to `editorWindow`

Then in your `createEditorWindow` method add

```
 editorWindow.add(createToolBar(), BorderLayout.WEST);
```

(You'll need to fix a couple other compiler errors generated by removing `extends JFrame`, but they should be pretty obvious)

Answer (score 0):

```
//editorWindow.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

You don't add the toolbar to the frame.

Do you realize you have two JFrames in your code? Your class extends JFrame and then in your code your also create another JFrame. Sometimes your code just used the `add(...)` method to add components to the class. And then sometimes your code uses `editorWindow.add(...)` to add components to the frame.

Your code is confusing because you have two frames. Don't extend JFrame.

Start with the `MenuLookDemo` code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). It will show you how to better structure your code so that you don't have two frames. The "create" methods should actually return components so they can be added to the frame.

Comment: *"Do you realize you have two JFrames in your code?"* - They have three actually, but lets wait for the `NullPointerException` question for that one ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, oops, I need to improve my counting skills :)